# How to uninstall VMware Workstation 8 Trial?

Tags: uninstall, vmware

I downloaded VMware Workstation 8 trial and need to remove it completely.
When I try to:

```
sudo vmware-installer -u vmware-workstation
```

It returns:

```
sudo: vmware-installer: command not found
```

I still have the trial bundle. So how can I remove VMware Workstation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long form:

```
sudo /usr/lib/vmware-installer --uninstall-product PRODUCT
```

Short form:

```
sudo /usr/lib/vmware-installer -u PRODUCT
```

For a list of which products are installed, you may run:

```
/usr/lib/vmware-installer --list-products
```

or:

```
/usr/lib/vmware-installer -l
```